# Check if there was a reaction with certain emoji - Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I would like to make an If statement which asks if the message was reacted with a specific emoji. I have researched and unfortunately found absolutely nothing, can anyone help?

Summe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a standard unicode emoji, you can check via something like `message.reactions.cache.find(v => v.name =='') !== undefined`. If it's a custom emoji (let's say it's `:my_emoji:`), then you can do something similar with `message.reactions.cache.find(v => v.name =='my_emoji') !== undefined`,

Comment: `!!message.reactions.cache.find(...)` should be preferred over `!== undefined`. ([about `!!`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT)). Also, custom emojis can have the same name in different guilds, so make sure to use the ID instead of the name.